# C# Hastable: Why can't find key

Tags: c#, dictionary, hash, key

if created a Point Class to use it an hash table. However if I try use the key I got a false back, which I don't understand because the key is in the table. I created a simple one down below. Can anybody tell what I do wrong? Thank you for helping out!

Code:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Hashtable myH = new Hashtable();
            
            Point akt = new Point(0, 0);
            Point n = new Point(0, 2);
            Point n2 = new Point(2, 2);
            
            myH.Add(n,akt);
            myH.Add(n2,akt);
        
            if (myH.ContainsKey("2, 2"))
            {
                WriteLine(myH["2, 2"]);
            }
            
        }
    }
```

```
class Point
{
    public int PLX { get; set; }
    public int PLY { get; set; }

    public Point(int x, int y)
    {
        PLX = x;
        PLY = y;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return PLX + ", " + PLY;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use the old non-generic `HashTable` anymore. Instead use a `Dictionary<Point, Point>`.

Comment: You add a `Point` key but `"2, 2"` is a string

Comment: This could work: `myH.Add(n.ToString(),akt);`

Comment: MyH.ContainsKey(new Point(2, 2)) should work